# Subtotal on particular column SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm a beginner with SSRS in SSDT and Visual Stutio 
I would like to display a matrix toolbox in my report with a particular disposition of data.
Imagine I have a column group contains argument A, B, C, D, E,...
I need to integrate a subtotal of data B+C+D for example and the subtotal column has to follow the D-column. I need to get something like that:

| A | B | C | D | Subtotal of B+C+D | E |

Is it possible ? How can I get this view in the report please ?
Thks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to set up a containing group, so that you've something like this:

[Container 1 - A], [Container 2 - B], [Container 2 - C], [Container 2 - D], [Container 3 - E]

That way you can just have a subtotal for the container group and set the column visibility to only show for "Container 2".  Ideally you'd use whatever property from the data makes you want to treat these groups differently, but you can also set up a calculated field for expediency:

- Right click on the data set and select "Add Calculated Field", which I'll call Container.
- The value could be set up with something akin to this: `=IIF(Fields!ColField.Value<="A","C1",IIF(Fields!ColField.Value>="E","C3","C2"))`
- Add a parent group to your A/B/C/D group and check "include footer", grouping on Container.
- Put the appropriate sums in that column.
- Right click on the column and check the "Show or hide based on an expression" radio button.
- Since it's the hidden criteria you're setting up, the expression would be: `=Fields!Container.Value<>"C2"`

And that should give you an inline subtotal that only shows for B-D.